# Keyboard scrolling with acceleration

Tags: emacs

One can easily map some key to scroll up.

```
(defun up1()
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up 1))
(defun up2()
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up 2))
(global-set-key "\M-]" 'up2)
```

I am looking instead for the following behavior. The first handful of
scrolls would call up1() and the subsequent ones would call up2().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```el
(setq my-scroll-counter 0)
(setq my-scroll-limit 5)

(defun up1()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command this-command)
      (incf my-scroll-counter)
    (setq my-scroll-counter 0))
  (if (> my-scroll-counter my-scroll-limit) 
      (scroll-up 2)
    (scroll-up 1)))

(global-set-key "\M-]" 'up1)
```

If you want something a little fancier, you calculate your scroll step dynamically based on how many times you repeat the command:

```el
(setq my-scroll-counter 0)
(setq my-maximum-scroll 20)
(setq my-scroll-acceleration 4)

(defun up1()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command this-command)
      (incf my-scroll-counter)
    (setq my-scroll-counter 0))
  (scroll-up (min 
               (+ 1 (/ my-scroll-counter my-scroll-acceleration)) 
               my-maximum-scroll)))

(global-set-key "\M-]" 'up1)
```

Comment: Not exactly.. I would like the "acceleration" to kick in only in keyboard repeat. The idea is that if I stop scrolling, it means I'd like to look more closely at the code currently visible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The acceleration kicks in whenever you call up1 more than `my-scroll-limit` times in a row without another command in between. What does 'in keyboard repeat' mean?

Comment: If you press a keyboard key, only one instance is entered, but if you hold it down, the key repeats and you get multiple instances. If I hold \M-], I'd like the scrolling to be initially slow, but to then accelerate. If I stop, I'd like the same behavior to restart.

Comment: Then all you need is add a timer to Tyler's solution so that pressing the key twice with too long a time interval doesn't increment the counter: https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/5322803